# How to increase UDPClient throughput

Tags: c#, linux, network-programming, .net-core, datagram

I am looking into performance of .NET Core on a linux box. Specifically making sure what kind of limitations may be from tools available within the framework itself.

I've been hitting the box with ~ 50,000 pps. So far, it seems ~ 20,000 pps is what the UDPClient has been able to achieve before a fair bit of packets get dropped. Using another tool (syslog-ng) there's a rare/low packet loss rate.

If I'm looking to handle upwards of 50K pps, is UdpClient able to handle this with proper tuning?

```
using (UdpClient udpListener = new UdpClient(_sysLogPort))
{
    udpListener.Client.ReceiveBufferSize = _bufferSize;

    while (!_cts.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        try
        {
            UdpReceiveResult result = await udpListener.ReceiveAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your main weapon here is to increase the size of the socket receive buffer, via SO_RCVBUFSIZ, however that shows up in the API you're using.

Comment: @EJP I believe the ReceiveBufferSize property is the part that handles this (I could be wrong), however the current packets being sent are quite small and the buffer limit is much greater than the packet currently being sent. It feels like some tuning I am possibly missing for the UdpClient since syslog-ng was able to handle this traffic with very little overflow

Comment: What is the packet size you are using to send packets to this program? Which tool are you using to send those packets? What processor type are you using? Can you confirm you are using the loopback interface (that is, the sender and your program are on the same Linux host)? Which version of dotnet are you using, on your Linux box: 1.0.4, older, more recent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if your app launches a new thread with `udpListener.ReceiveAsync();`, it waits for its termination before trying to receive a new packet. So there is only one thread at a time that handles a new received UDP packet to create an object of type UdpReceiveResult. So, it is rather similar to a **single-threaded** app: you do **not** make use of the opportunity to run on a multi-core system.

**You may get better rates** (depending on your hardware, obviously), with the following way to write your program. In this example, there is a pool of 5 threads that run in parallel to create multiple instances of UdpReceiveResult at the same time. Even if packets are handled by the kernel one at a time, the userland process of creating instances of UdpReceiveResult is done in parallel, with this way of programming.

```
// example of multithreaded UdpClient with .NET core on Linux
// works on Linux OpenSuSE LEAP 42.1 with .NET Command Line Tools (1.0.4)
// passed tests with "time nping --udp -p 5555 --rate 2000000 -c 52000 -H localhost > /dev/null"

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace hwapp {
  class Program {
    // listen to port 5555
    UdpClient udpListener = new UdpClient(5555);

    static void Main(string[] args) {
      Program p = new Program();
      // launch 5 threads
      Task t0 = p.listen("thread 0");
      Task t1 = p.listen("thread 1");
      Task t2 = p.listen("thread 2");
      Task t3 = p.listen("thread 3");
      Task t4 = p.listen("thread 4");
      t0.Wait(); t1.Wait(); t2.Wait(); t3.Wait(); t4.Wait();
    }

    public async Task listen(String s) {
      Console.WriteLine("running " + s);
      using (udpListener) {
        udpListener.Client.ReceiveBufferSize = 2000;
        int n = 0;
        while (n < 10000) {
          n = n + 1;
          try {
            UdpReceiveResult result = udpListener.Receive();
          } catch (Exception ex) {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```